# LIWC English Dictionary

Tags: nlp, text-analytics-api

How can I get the English dictionary of LIWC (Linguistic Inquiry and Word Count)?

I want to make an Arabic dictionary for LIWC based on the English Dictionary.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a academic or commercial licence here: http://liwc.wpengine.com/

Comment: I did, but I can't get the dictionary because it is encrypted.

Comment: Have you tried asking them?